# Standard matrix of a transformation, matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I know that the answer is $\left[\begin{matrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$,  but how to get the answer?

> Let $\mathcal{B} = \{ \mathbf{b}_1 , \mathbf{b}_2 \}$ be the basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbf{b}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$, $\mathbf{b}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$. Furthermore, let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation. The matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is $[T]_\mathcal{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right ]$.
>   What is the standard matrix of $T$?

---

Original problem: [image: The Problem]

Comment: [Hint](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+basis+matrix&oq=change+basis+matrix+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6635j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1)

Comment: You'll get a better response if you write the question here rather than linking to an image, and also explain what you have tried and which step you got stuck on.

Comment: @JohnDoe the hint helped, thanks :)

Comment: @AntoniMalecki great! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$\bbox{T = \left [ \begin{matrix} t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} \end{matrix} \right ]}, \quad \bbox{\mathcal{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]}$$
The change of basis is
$$\bbox{[T]_\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}^{-1} T \mathcal{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right ]}$$
First step is to calculate $\mathcal{B}^{-1}$. A 2×2 matrix is easiest to [invert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse#In_relation_to_its_adjugate) (if possible) via its [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). Simply put,
$$\bbox{\mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} \end{matrix} \right ]} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{\mathbf{M}^{-1} = \frac{1}{m_{11} m_{22} - m_{12} m_{21}} \left [ \begin{matrix} m_{22} & -m_{12} \\ -m_{21} & m_{11} \end{matrix} \right ]}$$
Applying this to $\mathcal{B}$, we get
$$\bbox{\mathcal{B}^{-1} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]}$$
Thus, you need to solve
$$\bbox{ \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right ]}$$
for $t_{11}$, $t_{12}$, $t_{21}$, and $t_{22}$.